# Visual Studio Code Git won't discard files

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

I have about 5000 files that I am unable to discard and VSCode keeps warning me that there are too many files. I'm not sure when I started tracking these files, but if I click on discard and then confirm the discard, nothing happens. Any ideas on how I can solve this?

Comment: What do you mean by "discard"? Do you mean delete? Untrack in git?

Comment: I mean delete and untrack. They aren't my files, but I might have cloned a project incorrectly.

Answer (score 1):

VSCode recently [renamed the "Clean" option onto "Discard"](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/20810).
But it is about unstaging current changes, not deleting files.

If you have too many files (that should not be part of the repo, for example because they are generated), simply delete them, then record your deletion (add and commit).
Then you will be able to push.

Additionally, consider adding them (or their parent folder) to a `.gitignore` file.

Answer (score 1):

this is from a while ago but for anyone else having this problem. The way I solved it was because I had clicked my home directory when using source control.

Try closing and reopening vs code and once the "open a folder" option comes up pick the specific project folder and the 5000 files should be reduced to the files you want